# VIM - ftplugin doesn't seem to work

Tags: vim, ftplugin

I'm using spf13's vim distribution https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim. I have been trying to use 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces for `.js` files, for that reason I have created a `js.vim` in `~/.vim/ftplugin`. Am I doing it wrong?

#### js.vim

```
    set shiftwidth=2                " Use indents of 2 spaces
    set tabstop=2                   " An indentation every two columns
    set softtabstop=2               " Use two spaces while editing
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The naming convention for ftplugin filenames is:

```
{filetype}.vim
```

In your case, the filetype is `javascript`, not `js`, so it would be:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim
```

or, better:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
```

Also, you must use `setlocal` instead of `set` to prevent your options from leaking to other buffers:

```
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal tabstop=2
setlocal softtabstop=2
```

Note that the default JavaScript ftplugin doesn't define a default tabwidth at all.

Comment: +1. It may sound hard to believe that vim distributions are considered harmful however Vim is is a long journey. Most distributions disrupt this natural journey. @romainl is giving this wisdom that only comes with years of Vim usage. I wish you well on your journey

Comment: @PeterRincker thank you for the feed back... i will try to go along with the journey. I think I'm going to start from a clean install right now. :)